# Confused about Complex Differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic.

I was trying to find 
$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \overline{f(z)}$.

(here $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}:=\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$)

I used the chain rule, letting $g(z)=\overline{z}$.

Then, I got $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} g=1$ and thus the derivative of $g \circ f$ should be $1*\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} f$, but this is just $0$.

Yet this finally result is very wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is $f(z)$? Or are you trying to find $\partial\overline{f}/\partial\,\overline{z}$ in terms of $\partial f/\partial z$?

Comment: f is an arbitrary holomorphic function. I've edited the question to add the definition of the differential operator.

Comment: Always $\left(\dfrac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}\right)=\overline{\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)}$